# Is there a way to find all existing subdomains of one main domain?

Tags: search, subdomain

I work for Johns Hopkins University, and our web culture here has been an unruled wilderness for many years. We're trying to get a handle on the enormous number of registered subdomains across our part of the web-universe, and even our IT department is having some trouble tracking down the unabridged list.

Is there a tool or a script that would do this quickly and semi-easily? I'm a developer and would write something but I want to find out if this wheel has been created already.

Alternatively, is there a fancy way to google search, more than just *.jhu.edu or site: .jhu.edu, because those searches turn up tons of sites that use "jhu.edu" in the end of their urls (ex. www.keywordspy.com/organic/domain.aspx?q=cer.jhu.edu)

Thanks for your thoughts on this one!

Comment: Domains would have to be nameserved from somewhere. Easiest would be to look at your DNS server configs and see what domains they're authoritative for.

Answer (score 1):

The Google search `site:*.jhu.edu` seems to work well for me.

That said, you can also use Wolfram Alpha. Using [this search](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=jhu.edu), in the third box click "Subdomains" and then in the new subdomains section that is created click "More".

Answer (score 0):

As @Mark B alluded to in his comment, the only way a domain name (sub or otherwise) has any real value is if a DNS service maps it to a server so that a browser can send it a request. The only way to track down all of the sub-domains is to track down their DNS entries. Thankfully, DNS servers are fairly easy to find, depending on the level of access you have to the network infrastructure and the authoritative DNS server for the parent domain.

If you are able to, you can pull DNS traffic from firewall logs in and around your network. That will let you find DNS servers that are being sent requests for your sub-domains.

Easier though would be to simply follow the DNS trail. The authoritative DNS server for your domain (jhu.edu) will have pointers to the other DNS servers that are authoritative for sub-domains (if your main one is not authoritative already).

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the domain registrar and have the proper authorization, you should be able to contact technical support and request the [zone file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_file) or even export it yourself depending on the provider.